# How to change multiple table rows' dates with one start date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now, when a start date is selected in each row and click ok, an end date will display accordingly. So each table row has to manually click a button to show the end date.

Im wondering is it possible that if i only select one start date and click ok, 
not only the first row end date is shown, but also 2nd , 3rd... etc rows' `start date` and `end date` will be automatically show accordingly to the interval days

PS: Please note that the number of rows are dynamic, coming from database and the total no of row is unknown.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you !!

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined){

  $(".addSkip").click(function() {
    // row instance to use `find()` for the other input classes
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var date = new Date($row.find(".start_date").val()+" 0:00:00"),
        days = parseInt($row.find(".days").val(), 10);
    
    console.log(date.getDate());
    console.log(days);

    if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

      $row.find(".end_date").val(date.toInputFormat());
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Date");
    }
  });

  Date.prototype.toInputFormat = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
  };
})
(jQuery, this, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<th>
start</th>

<th>end</th>
<th>interval</th>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="ok" class="addSkip"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
  <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10"> </td>

  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="ok" class="addSkip"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
  <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10"> </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <input type="button" size="10" value="ok" class="addSkip" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
<td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10">
 
  </tr>
</table>
```

desired result

```
 start            end            interval
 13/10/17       20/10/17          7
 20/10/17       23/10/17          3
 23/10/17       30/10/17          7
```

......
 etc

Comment: you want that all rows will show the same end date? or all end must show the value corresponding to the relative start?

Comment: so, you want that inserting one date in the first start_date to 2017-01-01 (ex), the script elaborate the relative end_date and set the other start_date to 2017-01-02, 2017-01-03, etc. elaborating each end_date, right?

Comment: that's correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the "ok" button in favour of a simpler change event (both on date_start and days) and added the logic for your need! if something is not clear, don't esitate to ask clarifications ;)

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined){
$('input.start_date, input.days').on('change',function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
      $start = $row.find('.start_date'),
      $end = $row.find('.end_date'),
      $other = $row.find('.otherfield'),
      $interval = $row.find('.days'),
      date = new Date($start.val()+" 0:00:00"),
        days = parseInt($interval.val(), 10);
    
    console.log(date.getDate());
    console.log(days);

    if (!isNaN(date.getTime())) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);

      $end.val(date.toInputFormat());
      $other.val(date.toInputFormat());
      $row.next('tr')
        .find('.start_date').val(date.toInputFormat()).trigger('change');
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid Date");
    }
  });

  Date.prototype.toInputFormat = function() {
    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
    return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
  };
})
(jQuery, this, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>start</th>
    <th>end</th>
    <th>other</th>
    <th>interval</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
      <td><textarea class="otherfield"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
      <td><textarea class="otherfield"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10"> </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><input type="date" size="15" name="date[]" class="start_date" \>
      <td><input type="text" size="15" name="nextdate[]" class="end_date"  \> </td>
      <td><textarea class="otherfield"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="3" name="skip[]" class="days" value="10"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the thing is each row end date should be next row start date.

Comment: ops, my misunderstanding :D I've fixed the code: now each time a .start_date or a .days is changed will propagate the change to the next start date ;)

Comment: oops just one more issue, sorry if i have a textarea for each row that's right next to the end date, can i copy the end date to each of them as well

Comment: obviously you can, i've edited the code that way (and fixed some html mistype)

Answer (score 1):

In jquery, you can do something like this to find multiple element:

`$row.find("*[class^=".end_date"]")`

For more details, refer [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Try just ```$("[class=".end_date"]")``` without ```$row.find```